# What is the max sd card size for the LG optimus dynamic

Tags: external-sd, storage

What is the maximum size of sdcard that LG optimus dynamic supports?

Answer (score 1):

LG on its website [here](http://www.lg.com/us/cell-phones/lg-LGL38C-optimus-dynamic) has featured the specifications for your device, and the relevant one is:

> microSD™ Memory Slot                             Supports up to 32 GB memory card**

Now you can buy the micro-SD card of size up to 32GB.

Answer (score 0):

As per [This](http://tracfonereviewer.blogspot.in/2013/11/lg-optimus-dynamic-review-tracfone.html?m=1) it supports Micro sdcard upto 32GB.